# Pandas dataframe datetime to time then to seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have a dataframe. A column contains timestamps. I would like to remove dates and convert the time to seconds.

First I converted them to datetime:

```
In:
df_time = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])

Out:
0     2017-11-07 13:09:00
1     2017-11-07 13:11:00
2     2017-11-07 13:13:00
3     2017-11-07 13:15:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Then I removed dates:

```
In:
df_time = pd.Series([val.time() for val in df_time])

Out:
0      13:09:00
1      13:11:00
2      13:13:00
3      13:15:00
4      13:17:00
dtype: object
```

But they became objects and I did not managed to convert them to datetime-like objects to convert them into seconds. I know there are some similar threads I went trhough them.

I thank your help in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you are converting it to datetime series, simply use basic maths  to get the seconds i.e

```
df_time = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])

(df_time.dt.hour*60+df_time.dt.minute)*60 + df_time.dt.second

0    47340
1    47460
2    47580
3    47700
Name: Timestamp, dtype: int64
```

Comment: After I implement it, it gives two errors:
1:
    TypeError: cannot convert an object of type <class 
    'pandas.core.series.Series'> to a datetimelike index
2:
    AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: Need `df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])` as first step ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need `timedelta`s by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with `times` created by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and selecting second `list`s by `str[1]`, then [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and last cast to `int`:

```
df_time = pd.to_timedelta(df["Timestamp"].str.split().str[1]).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
print (df_time)
0    47340
1    47460
2    47580
3    47700
Name: Timestamp, dtype: int32
```

Detail:

```
print (df["Timestamp"].str.split().str[1])
0    13:09:00
1    13:11:00
2    13:13:00
3    13:15:00
Name: Timestamp, dtype: object

print (pd.to_timedelta(df["Timestamp"].str.split().str[1]))
0   13:09:00
1   13:11:00
2   13:13:00
3   13:15:00
Name: Timestamp, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

---

Or if need seconds form `datetime`s use [`dt.second`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.second.html):

```
df_time = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"]).dt.second
print (df_time)
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
Name: Timestamp, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Maybe str is bit too much for a datetime column

Comment: Hmm, problem is it is not datetime column, so first step is convert to datetime.

Answer (score 1):

if you are substracting for duration then use below to convert in seconds
(tsession['EndTime'] -tsession['StartTime'])/ np.timedelta64(1, 's')