# Pandas read_csv with different date parsers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, panel-data

I have a csv-file with time series data, the first column is the date in the format `%Y:%m:%d` and the second column is the intraday time in the format '%H:%M:%S'. I would like to import this csv-file into a multiindex dataframe or panel object.

With this code, it already works:

```
    _file_data = pd.read_csv(_file,
                         sep=",",
                         header=0,
                         index_col=['Date', 'Time'],
                         thousands="'",
                         parse_dates=True,
                         skipinitialspace=True
                         )
```

It returns the data in the following format:

```
Date         Time                   Volume
2016-01-04   2018-04-25 09:01:29    53645
             2018-04-25 10:01:29    123
             2018-04-25 10:01:29    1345
             ....
2016-01-05   2018-04-25 10:01:29    123
             2018-04-25 12:01:29    213
             2018-04-25 10:01:29    123
```

1st question: 
I would like to show the second index as a pure time-object not datetime. To do that, I have to declare two different date-pasers in the read_csv function, but I can't figure out how. What is the "best" way to do that?

2nd question:
After I created the Dataframe, I converted it to a panel-object. Would you recommend doing that? Is the panel-object the better choice for such a data structure? What are the benefits (drawbacks) of a panel-object?

Comment: For your 1st question see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48129251/9400024)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1st question**:

You can create multiple `converters` and define parsers in dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""Date,Time,Volume
2016:01:04,09:00:00,53645
2016:01:04,09:20:00,0
2016:01:04,09:40:00,0
2016:01:04,10:00:00,1468
2016:01:05,10:00:00,246
2016:01:05,10:20:00,0
2016:01:05,10:40:00,0
2016:01:05,11:00:00,0
2016:01:05,11:20:00,0
2016:01:05,11:40:00,0
2016:01:05,12:00:00,213"""
```

---

```
def converter1(x):
    #convert to datetime and then to times
    return pd.to_datetime(x).time()

def converter2(x):
    #define format of datetime
    return pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y:%m:%d')

#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), 
                 index_col=['Date','Time'], 
                 thousands="'",
                 skipinitialspace=True,
                 converters={'Time': converter1, 'Date': converter2})

print (df)
                     Volume
Date       Time            
2016-01-04 09:00:00   53645
           09:20:00       0
           09:40:00       0
           10:00:00    1468
2016-01-05 10:00:00     246
           10:20:00       0
           10:40:00       0
           11:00:00       0
           11:20:00       0
           11:40:00       0
           12:00:00     213
```

Sometimes is possible use built-in parser, e.g. if format of dates is `YY-MM-DD`:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""Date,Time,Volume
2016-01-04,09:00:00,53645
2016-01-04,09:20:00,0
2016-01-04,09:40:00,0
2016-01-04,10:00:00,1468
2016-01-05,10:00:00,246
2016-01-05,10:20:00,0
2016-01-05,10:40:00,0
2016-01-05,11:00:00,0
2016-01-05,11:20:00,0
2016-01-05,11:40:00,0
2016-01-05,12:00:00,213"""
```

---

```
def converter(x):
    #define format of datetime
    return pd.to_datetime(x).time()

#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), 
                 index_col=['Date','Time'], 
                 parse_dates=['Date'],
                 thousands="'",
                 skipinitialspace=True,
                 converters={'Time': converter})

print (df.index.get_level_values(0))
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-04', '2016-01-04', '2016-01-04', '2016-01-04',
               '2016-01-05', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-05',
               '2016-01-05', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-05'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

Last possible solution is convert `datetime` to times in `MultiIndex` by [`set_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html) - after processing:

```
df.index = df.index.set_levels(df.index.get_level_values(1).time, level=1)
print (df)
                     Volume
Date       Time            
2016-01-04 09:00:00   53645
           09:20:00       0
           09:40:00       0
           10:00:00    1468
2016-01-05 10:00:00     246
           10:00:00       0
           10:20:00       0
           10:40:00       0
           11:00:00       0
           11:20:00       0
           11:40:00     213
```

---

**2nd question**:

**Panel** in pandas 0.20.+ is [deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dsintro-deprecate-panel) and will be removed in a future version.

Comment: Unfortunately, only the last (least possible) solution works. With the first two solutions print (df.index.get_level_values(0)) still prints a dateformat.

Comment: @Krasnars - What is your pandas version?

Comment: I have pandas 0.22.0

Comment: Actually, it worked out. Maybe I had a type on the first time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To convert to a time series use `pd.to_timedelta`.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Time": ["2018-04-25 09:01:29", "2018-04-25 10:01:29", "2018-04-25 10:01:29"]})
df["Time"] = pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(df["Time"]).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
print df["Time"]
```

**Output:**

```
0   09:01:29
1   10:01:29
2   10:01:29
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already did this approach and it worked. But, I was looking for a way to transform the data while reading the csv-file.

Comment: @Krasnars - There is some problem?