# Convert a string to a timestamp in a different unit than nanoseconds

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert a string in a timestamp using the pandas `to_datetime` method. I would like that the result should be not in nanoseconds but in a different unit.

With nanoseconds everything works well

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime('11/11/97')
```

instead with a different unit I get this error:

```
pd.to_datetime('11/11/97', unit='s')
```

> ValueError: non convertible value 11/11/97 with the unit 's'

Comment: You could do a normal math division to obtain the unit you need

Comment: do you mean this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129251/pandas-dataframe-datetime-to-time-then-to-seconds

Comment: Actually I need to use datetime and then for certain dates subtract 100 years. But with nanoseconds I get an error: TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O'). this the reason why I need a different time unit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert string to datetime type, you can use `datetime.strptime(str, format)` to convert it. For example,

```
from datetime import datetime
t = datetime.strptime('11/11/97', '%m/%d/%y')
>>> datetime.datetime(1997, 11, 11, 0, 0)
```

Also, for subtracting 100 years from the certain date, you can use `datetime.timedelta()`.

```
from datetime import timedelta
t_100yrs_ago = t - timedelta(36500)
>>> datetime.datetime(1897, 12, 5, 0, 0)
t_100yrs_ago = t - timedelta(36524)
>>> datetime.datetime(1897, 11, 11, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert datetime and then simply use timestamp.

```
t = pd.to_datetime('11/11/97')

print(t.timestamp())
```

Also, if you have column which you want to convert to seconds, then you can use

```
df['columnName'].dt.total_seconds()
```

more information: [pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html)